# Is std::cin >> i >> ++i; undefined behavior

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, operator-precedence, evaluation

I am trying to understand the order of evaluation of expressions in C++. I have the following examples:

```
int i = 0;
std::cin >> i >> i; //IS THIS UB?
```

My first question is that does the above shown snippet produces UB?

Next,

```
int i = 0;
std::cin >> i >> ++i; //IS THIS UB?
```

My second question is that does this snippet produces UB?

Comment: I'm really curious about the use case for `std::cin >> i >> ++i;` Incrementing a variable, and then immediately overwrite the value. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am learning about evaluation of expressions, so just wanted to know if this causes UB or not. For example, i think `std::cout << i << ++i;` will cause UB but then why not `std::cin >> i >> ++i;`.

Comment: You don't really have to know all the details, if you just write code where the order doesn't matter. And specify the order (using separate statements) where it does matter. For example, I believe that `std::cin >> i >> i;` is technically ok, but would still write it as `std::cin >> ignored >> i;` to show that I really only wanted the second value.

Comment: My question is why would you write code that is hard to understand. In any professional environment, you are going to be called out on this kind of bad style and made to go and make it more explicitly clear.

Comment: @BoP: what about `std::cin >> a[i] >> a[++i];` instead.

Comment: @MartinYork When you're learning something you get curious. And the next big step in learning is to get curious enough to ask the question from some experts(teacher, on SO etc). This is what i did. I got curious enough to ask this question. This will help me understand why i shouldn't write code like this in the future. I prefer to ask(clear out) my doubts and not care about what others say.

Comment: @Yves - You can just do `std::cin >> a[i] >> a[i+1];` and not mix I/O with computations (another rule of thumb). Writing tricky code makes it hard for the human reader without helping the compiler in any way. It is not that `++i` is faster than `i + 1`, or anything.

Comment: @BoP: the question is not about "what should I do" but about "is it UB". I gave you a use case that is less made, and is a terrible trap of C++. I wouldn't call updating the index on the fly "a computation" (any array access would be a computation, then).

Comment: @Yves - I would call updating the index a computation. If you input or output a pair of values from an array, you can use index `i` and `i+1`, and then have `i += 2` in the surrounding for-loop. Why change the loop counter halfway through (being UB or not)?

Comment: @BoP: you may call it a side effect. Not a computation.

Answer (score 3):

`std::cin >> i >> i;` is and always was well-defined.

`std::cin >> i >> ++i;` is well-defined now, but was UB pre-C++17.

This kind of UB is [caused either by](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Undefined_behavior) unsequenced writes to the same scalar, or a write unsequenced relative to a read of the same scalar.

In `std::cin >> i >> i;`, even though `i` is modified twice (inside of the overloaded `>>`), the first modification is sequenced before the second one. The return value of the first `>>` has to be calculated first, to be passed as an argument to the second `>>`, so they have to be called in this order. [See rule (3) here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

In `std::cin >> i >> ++i;`, on the other hand, pre-C++17 the modification of `i` by the first `>>` was unsequenced relative to `++i`, causing UB. But in C++17 and newer, `>>` and `<<` always evaluate the lhs before rhs, causing the first `>>` to be sequenced before `++i`, [see rule (19) here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Comment: *even though `i` is modified twice* This is not true, `i` may be left unmodified.

Comment: @MartinYork Thanks, should be better now.

Comment: @S.M. Yes, but that shouldn't affect the well-defined-ness? Note that OP zeroed it.

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't affect the well-defined-ness. The variable value is unspecified in the result, may be 1, or incremented first input, or second input.

Answer (score 0):

##### Case I

In this case, `std::cin >> i >> i;` can be written as(or equivalent to):

```
std::cin.operator>>(i).operator>>(i);
```

There are 2 important things to consider here

1. `std::cin::operator>>` returns `cin` object by reference
2. Each call to `std::cin>>operator>>` is guaranteed to be made in order from left to right.

So there is no undefined behavior in this case.

##### Case II

In this case, `std::cin >> i >> ++i;` can be written as(or equivalent to):

```
std::cin.operator>>(i).operator>>(++i);
```

Now, from [Section 1.9, Point 16](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1804.pdf):

> When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), there is a sequence point after the evaluation of all function arguments (if any) which takes place before execution of any expressions or statements in the function body. There is also a sequence point after the copying of a returned value and before the execution of any expressions outside the function.

But note that the above quote statement only guarantees that:

1. `i` is evaluated before the first call to `operator>>` and
2. `++i` is evaluated before the second call to `operator>>`.

But the quote **doesn't guarantee** that `i` is evaluated before `++i` or vice versa. This means that the order in which `i` and `++i` are evaluated is **undefined** and so the resulting code in this case will have **undefined behavior**.

The above discussion(sequence points) is for **Pre-C++11** since OP didn't tag C++11.

Comment: Sequence points were removed in C++11, you're quoting some old standard.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The OP didn't tag `C++11` so i gave answer accordingly.

Comment: You are right, I misread it, it has such a member.

Comment: @AnoopRana Then I suggest explicitly mentioning which standard revisions the answer applies to.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Added a note at the end of my answer. Check it out.

Comment: @AnoopRana C++ is not C++98, C++ is C++ as specified by the *current* ISO standard. This doesn't need to be specifically tagged. OTOH C++98 questions do need to be tagged. They are not about C++, they are about a historical version of C++  that is hardly relevant today.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. In any case, i have mentioned at the end of my answer, so that people(future readers) who are not already aware that this is pre-C++11 will know(get aware of that fact).